# Asked to pay money to strangers who asked me to download trust wallet app on my phone

Tags: wallet

Was approached by a stranger who said i could invest without using my money
Was asked to download trust wallet and then asked to creat a wallet
Asked me to send 200 usd which i did
Then they said they is still an issue
Asked me to send another 200 usd which i did
Then told how to create a new wallet - they sent me a long code for me to enter and suddenly i had a view only wallet showing 32 K USD
Was then asked to send 300 gbp to complete - which i did

Now no furhter forward and they asking for another 200 gbp to complete which i have refused
The person advised that their father was a billionaire and he wanted to encourage people to invest in Trust Wallet

I now guess this is a big scam which of course they have denied and they actually personal photograph of themselves to convince me to pay

Comment: Typically, you will now be contacted by scammers pretending to be recovery agents.